# Using OrderedDict() to print python class members

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to simulate the problem statement using the below program:

```
import json

class System:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = "abc"
        self.fwVersion = "123"
        self.prevfwVersion = "456"
        self.safemodeVersion = "5756"

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.__dict__[key] = val

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def toJSON(self):
        return self.__dict__

class Mainwall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.system = System()

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.__dict__[key] = val

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def toJSON(self):
        return self.__dict__


class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'toJSON'):
            return obj.toJSON()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

fw = Mainwall()

def my_print():
    print(json.dumps(fw.toJSON(), cls=ComplexEncoder, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_print()
```

Since python dictionary does not preserve the insertion order , the output of the above program is always will have the different key order.

Say, first time it prints:

```
{
    "system": {
        "safemodeVersion": "5756",
        "prevfwVersion": "456",
        "fwVersion": "123",
        "model": "abc"
    }
}
```

Second time it prints:

```
{
    "system": {
        "fwVersion": "123",
        "prevfwVersion": "456",
        "safemodeVersion": "5756",
        "model": "abc"
   }
```

}

But, in the output I would like to preserve the order in which the class members are initialized. i.e., Exactly as below:

```
{
    "system": {
        "model": "abc",
        "fwVersion": "123",
        "prevfwVersion": "456",
        "safemodeVersion": "5756",

    }
}
```

How to achieve the expected output for the same example using OrderedDict() or some other method?

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: python version:3.6

Comment: Dicts preserves order in Python 3.6

Comment: I cannot reproduce, `dict` objects are suppose to preserve insertion order, and object name-spaces, `__dict__` are quite plainly `dict` objects.

Comment: maybe you should check python version. Inpython3.6, dict is ordered. In python2, you can use collections.OrderedDict() to wrap self.__dicit__

Comment: Hey it is Python 3.5.2

Comment: @abccd: at the moment the fact that py3.6 dicts preserve insertion order is still an implementation detail and not part of the language spec so one should not rely on this behaviour.

Comment: @ShanthaDodmane why do you care about insertion order here ? The JSON spec clearly states that json objects are _unordered_ collections of key:value pairs. Also, your "toJSON" method should be named "to_dict", since what it returns is a Python dict, not a json string.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around I made for you. I invite you to look into the `System()` class. I created an `OrderedDict()` instead of four `self` attributes. Then, in you method `toJSON(self):`, instead of returning the `self.__dict__` attributes, I am returning the `OrderedDict()` I set earlier.

```
class System:
    def __init__(self, model='abc', fwVersion='123', prevfwVersion='456', safemodeVersion='5756'):
        self.my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
        self.my_ordered_dict['model'] = model
        self.my_ordered_dict['fwVersion'] = fwVersion
        self.my_ordered_dict['prevfwVersion'] = prevfwVersion
        self.my_ordered_dict['safemodeVersion'] = safemodeVersion
        # self.model = "abc"
        # self.fwVersion = "123"
        # self.prevfwVersion = "456"
        # self.safemodeVersion = "5756"

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.__dict__[key] = val

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def toJSON(self):
        return self.my_ordered_dict
```

This `System()` class instead of the one above, with the same code, outputs...

```
{
    "system": {
        "model": "abc", 
        "fwVersion": "123", 
        "prevfwVersion": "456", 
        "safemodeVersion": "5756"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to python 3.6 solved the problem.

Comment: Well, upgrading to 3.6 is a solution. I invite you to look at my answer that could have worked in 3.5.2, as It works in python 2.7.